# Reactjs and SCSS - how to write height: selfheight x 2

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to double the height of the div every time it is clicked.

I am thinking to apply a additional CSS class to a div when ever I click a button. The CSS concept will be like:

```
#divToBeDoubled {
    height: 100px;

    &.doubleHeight{
        height: selfHeight*2
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this by using Reactjs and SCSS?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using css ? You can directly do it in the JSX file.

Comment: Would also be great if it can be achieved directly using JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want to change a css value with the component state, you need to move the property you want to change in you component or use JSS...

to move the property in the render, you can do this :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{

  state = {
    divHeight : 100
  }

  doubleSize = ()=>{
    this.setState({ divHeight : this.state.divHeight * 2 })
  }

  render() {

    const style = {
      height: this.state.divHeight
    };

    return (
      <div style={style} onClick={this.doubleSize}>Content</div>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If using sass. You can use this, and toggle class in JSX onclick event.

```
$height: 100px;
.normal {
    height: $height;
}
.double {
    height: $height * 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! But I think this will only double the height for the first time of click?